# I want to use shift function in pandas Dataframe for filing missing value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply, shift

I want to use shift function in pandas Dataframe for filing missing value..

I try:

```
ex_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,4,7,3,5],'b': [4, 5,8,2,6],'c': [0, 0,1,1,0],'d':[3,np.nan,9,np.nan,np.nan]})
print(ex_df)

ex_df.info()
print(type(ex_df['a']))
ex_df['d'] = ex_df.apply(
    lambda row: row['a'].shift(1)*row['b'].shift(1) if pd.isnull(row['d']) else row['d'],
    axis=1
)
```

get error:

```
[![AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift' ][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the apply function in this way it is acting on specific row values instead of a series or dataframe, so it doesnt have access to the shift command.

It needs to be written so the shift command is acting the series.

Try something like this.

```
df['d']=df['d'].fillna(df[['a','b']].shift(1).sum(axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `apply` method then following should work. You just need  to pass your shifted dataframe/series in apply's [`args`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) parameter.

```
ex_df['d'] = ex_df.apply(
    lambda row,a_s,b_s: a_s[row.name]*b_s[row.name] if pd.isnull(row['d']) else row['d'],
    axis=1,
    args = [ex_df['a'].shift(1),ex_df['b'].shift(1)]
)

ex_df
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c   d
0   1   4   0   3.0
1   4   5   0   4.0
2   7   8   1   9.0
3   3   2   1   56.0
4   5   6   0   6.0
```